# How to use multiple delimiter in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

**I'm trying to split the elements into new elements, from this format :**

```
<KK>
    <LABEL>ABITIBI</LABEL>
    <SECTION.DEP>FLOW|GOAL|CABINET</SECTION.DEP>
   <FRAMES.FRAME.CORNER_MISSION>PRE_PRA|PRO_PRU</FRAMES.FRAME.CORNER_MISSION>
</KK>
```

**to this format:**

```
<KK>
    <LABEL>ABITIBI</LABEL>
    <SECTION>
        <DEP>FLOW</DEP>
        <DEP>GOAL</DEP>
        <DEP>CABINET</DEP>
    </SECTION>
    <FRAMES>
        <FRAME>
            <CORNER>PRE</CORNER>
            <MISSION>PRA</MISSION>
        </FRAME>
        <FRAME>
            <CORNER>PRO</CORNER>
            <MISSION>PRU</MISSION>
        </FRAME>
    </FRAMES>
</KK>
```

**Using this Code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), '.')]" name="nest">
    <xsl:param name="name" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'.'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($name, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before($name, $delimiter)}" >
                <!-- recursive call -->
                <xsl:call-template name="nest">
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="substring-after($name, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <xsl:element name="{$name}" >
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The tricky step that i couldn't do is how to use **multiple delimiters** and access **layers and levels** to write the needed XML format.

Comment: Can you use xslt 2.0?

Comment: No its xslt 1.0 :(